# Restart policies in docker container

Tags: docker, signals, restart

I enabled `docker container` to restart automatically during crashes/system reboots etc.

For this we applied the `docker restart policy to always` for an already running container .

Sent a `SIGHUP` signal but the `container` did not stated automatically

```
      sudo docker kill --signal=SIGHUP 5b61a7735329
      5b61a7735329
      $ sudo docker ps
      CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

On `restarting the docker container` using below command , the container process  starts automatically as verified by `docker ps`

```
      $ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

1. Any suggestions why it is not starting automatically when we manually send the `SIGHUP` signal.
2. Will it automatically restart for any docker failures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
always: Always restart a stopped container unless the container was stopped explicitly
```

You stopped it with docker kill.
You should use "on-failure". SIGHUP is not a normal exit and should trigger a restart.

```
on-failure: Restart the container if it exited with a non-zero exit code or if the docker daemon restarts
```

...